# Using class template and overloading / operators

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading

Heloo, I'm having trouble with overloading the / operator in a member function within a template class. I get the error 'error C2805: binary 'operator /' has too few parameters' but I think I'm giving the operator enough parameters. Here is part of my header file code

```
template <class T>
typename complex<T>::complex operator/(complex<T> &c)  
{  
    complex temp; 
    temp.re = (re*c.getRe() + im*c.getIm())/(pow(c.getRe(),2)+pow(c.getIm(),2));    
    temp.im = (im*c.getRe() - re*c.getIm())/(pow(c.getRe(),2)+pow(c.getIm(),2)); 
    return temp;  
}
```

My function declaration is given below

```
T operator/(complex<T> &c);
```

My declaration is indside the class template and the declaration outside, but within the same namespace. If you need the whole code please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the class prefix in the operator definition:

```
complex<T>::operator /(complex<T> &c)
```

Also, you declared the operator as returning `T` - why are you returning `complex` in the definition?

Comment: Sorry, the class prefix? What do you mean by this? I have also changed the declaration of the function from T to complex and the number of errors I get has gone down drastically. Thank you.

Comment: @user1303032, when you define the implementation of a member function outside of the class declaration, you need to precede the function name with class name like this: classA::func1.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaring a new free function, not the one you declared inside the class definition.

```
template <class T>
typename complex<T>::complex  operator/(complex<T> &c)  
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
            return type       function name
```

You can see what you're missing there - the scope resolution. You can only overload binary operators as free functions, hence the compiler error you're getting.

This would match your in-class declaration:

```
template<class T>
T complex<T>::operator/(complex<T>& c)
{
    // ...
}
```

Compilable example:

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/J6ruN)

Then again, returning the template parameter alone from `operator/` is probably not what you wanted, you'd want to return a class instance instead. So I think what you really need is this:

```
template<class T>
complex<T> complex<T>::operator/(const complex<T>& c)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain to me why two complex<T>'s are needed?

Comment: @Gar Which of the two confuses you?

Comment: I'm just wondering why the complex<T> is needed before the complex<T>::operator... part?

Comment: It declares return type of the function. Now considering the declaration you provided (`T operator/(complex<T> &c);`), a call to `operator/` on a class instantiated like `complex<int>` will return an `int`. If you instead, you'd want it to return another instance of the same class, the return type would need to be `complex<T>`. I hope that's clear.